# ORA-210000 Oracle error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Tags: oracle

I am trying to setup  a connection from my rhel 7.9 machine to my oracle host db on windows server 2016 running oracle 19c.

04:25:36 - ORA-210000 Oracle error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

I've downloaded and installed 2 clients, version 19 and 21 hoping that it would resolve the issue but it doesnt. My tnsnames.ora file is being used in another windows installation to connect to the same oracle db host and works fine, but fails on the linux vm.

```
 /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_5/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
/opt/oracle/instantclient_19_14/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

any ideas what it could be?

[image: error]

Also, any idea why the following file is flashing? is there an error, this is all my local environment im learning linux, but not sure why this is flashing.

[image]

Also installed sql plus and i got the following error, btw how do I know sqlplus is referencing correctly tnsnames.ora file?

Here is my environment variables

export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_25
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

[image]

Comment: `sqlplus is referencing correctly tnsnames.ora file` TNSPing usually shows this in the output.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/connect.htm#NETAG378

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

I would suggest that connections through TNS generally look more like this:

```
username@tns_alias
```

Given only a single entry, I'm pretty sure that Oracle will assume that you've given it a *username* and that you want to connect to the database identified by the **ORACLE_SID** environment variable.

Try something more like ...

```
sqlplus username@ACCFDA
```

... and see if you get any further.

(I recommend *not* using any of the "as sys..." options remotely.
If you want to do anything "serious" with your database, get yourself onto the local host to do it!).